# SQL Foreign key abrevation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys

Are these T-SQL declarations equals?

```
CREATE TABLE Person
(
ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
NAME VARCHAR(60)
)

CREATE TABLE Dog
(
CHIP_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
OWNER_ID INT REFERENCES Person(ID)
)
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE Person
(
ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
NAME VARCHAR(60)
)

CREATE TABLE Dog
(
CHIP_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
OWNER_ID INT,
FOREIGN KEY(OWNER_ID) REFERENCES Person(ID)
)
```

I'm talking of course about the foreign key, I'm not sure if I have to specify it is a foreign key or not.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, they are identical. You could even reduce the first one to `OWNER_ID INT REFERENCES Person` if I'm not mistaken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the DBMS see both as the same. But humans can many times miss important details when the code is cryptic. In fact, my preference is this:

```
CREATE TABLE Person(
    ID     INT not null,
    Name   VARCHAR(60) not null,
    constraint PK_Person primary key( ID )
);

CREATE TABLE Dog(
    ID       INT not null,
    OwnerID  INT,
    constraint PK_Dog primary key( CHIP_ID ),
    constraint FK_Dog_Owner foreign key( OWNER_ID ) REFERENCES Person( ID )
);
```

Using the `constraint` clause not only defines the primary and foreign keys, but allow us to give them a meaningful name. And the surrogate key of each table should be named "ID". Any foreign keys in other tables will expand that name according to its context (RoleID). As you have in the `Dog` table with `OwnerID`. Another table with a FK to the same Person table may name it `GroomerID` or whatever else shows the role that person plays in the context of the table.

Also, as you can see, I prefer CamelCase with SQL Server, leaving `OWNER_ID` for Oracle.

Some even go so far as to place either NULL or NOT NULL after each column definition. But I find that adds clutter and doesn't really supply information even a beginning SQL developer doesn't already know. So I only supply NOT NULL when appropriate and let the default carry. Actually, in the later versions of Oracle and SQL Server, the NOT NULL for the primary key field is optional as the primary key is going to be defined as NOT NULL no matter what.

Long ago there seemed to be an informal contest to see who could cram the most operations into the fewest words or even characters. Just stay far away from that kind of thinking. But do make everything you write meaningful.

In general, use every opportunity to add *meaningful* information to the code. The computer doesn't care. Write to the other developers who will follow you.

Comment: In general I agree with your answer, but: "*And the surrogate key of each table should be named ID*" - is very much personal taste and you'll find a lot of people around here that would not agree with you on that - including me. I find this naming scheme rather distracting and obfuscating - but every team has their own coding standards.

Comment: Yes, naming conventions are like dress codes, tailored to fit the environment. But I like to name each field of a table according to the context established by the table. A natural key will, of course, be named as it fits its contents, but a surrogate key serves no purpose other than to be the unique identifier of the table. So they should all be called...whatever, but the same name. Otherwise you can get weird aliases like "select customer_id as owner_id..." rather than "select id as owner_id...". The generic "ID" carries no left-over context so there is no battle of the contexts going on.

Comment: Oh, and I don't doubt one minute that I'll "find a lot of people around here that would not agree with you on that..." I don't come here to hear my own ideas echoing back at me. I *want* to hear other ideas. Disagree please! Everyone benefits from energetic but rational debate (versus flame wars). Although I'm sure any lengthy discussion will have to be taken up at a different venue.

Answer (score 0):

Both T-SQL will create the foreign key you need. However, I believe the second approach where the code explicitely states "FOREIGN KEY..." is a good contribution to keep easy-maintenance and clean code for future software engineer understanding.